# Multidata trigger condition for listbox to check if an item is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to disable a button if there are no items in the listbox.

I am now confused on which property I should check in the Multidata trigger condition for the listbox in order to check whether there is any element in the listbox. Please help.

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=JobItemsListBox, Path=ItemsSource}" 
                   Value="">
        </Condition>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: Have you tried `Path=Items.Count` and `Value="0"`?

Comment: Sorry. But it doesn't seem to work in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qqww2 comment is correct -- this works

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: hmm... try creating a separate test app -- with just the button and listbox and add a few items in the ListBox.  In the button click do listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0) ... I can post the code if you need.

Comment: Yea I got the issue. Actually it had 3 conditions inside <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>. 2 were related conditions which was binding to 2 checkboxes' checked states. When this was added to it, it did not work. I separated the conditions and it seems to be working fine. Thanks for the help anyway!